# Back button in navigation controller wont change to custom image

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have two VC, the first of which is embedded in a NC. My second VC is presented using a push segue from my first VC. In my second VC, I am trying to change the back button to a custom image I have, but it is still using the default image and text in the navigation bar.

viewDidLoad() in my second VC:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let back = UIImage(named: "back")
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = back
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = back
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    configureView()
}
```

Why is the following not changing the back button in my second VC?

Comment: Move it to viewWillAppear or DidAppear

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov Neither of these worked

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is line that sets the `backButtonItem`, replacing anything you've done to the  back button with a new back button.  Just remove:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: I must be doing something else fundamentally wrong here because this didn't seem to change anything either.

Comment: @Brejuro, as a debug step, do this in a brand new project.  Push from one VC to another, include this code in the second one.  It works on my system (and fails to work when I include your extra line creating a button).

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the title to `""`, if you do not need a title set the title to `nil`. Can't comment, not enough reputation, sorry. See from the docs:

"The item’s title. If nil a title is not displayed."

Answer (score 0):

You need to set it on the first view controller.

Calling the following code on your first view controller.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let back = UIImage(named: "back")
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorImage = back
    self.navigationController!.navigationBar.backIndicatorTransitionMaskImage = back
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: nil, action: nil)

    configureView()
}
```

More details
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-change-back-button-image/
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-remove-text-from-uinavigationbar-back-button/